# angular ui grid call html.action link in cell temlpate

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, grid

```
{
    name: 'Actions', width: '30%', enableFiltering: false, enableSorting: false, enableColumnMenu: false,
    cellTemplate: '<div class="grid-action-cell">' +
                  '<a @Html.ActionLink("ViewByHtml", "GetCountryById", "Country", new { id= "row.entity.inCntId" },  new { data_modal = "", id = "{{row.entity.inCntId}}" })>{{row.entity.inCntId}} </a>' +                      
                  '</div>'
}
```

Comment: inside cell directive normal html will not poppulate

Comment: then ther is any alternative to open modal on cell click

Comment: yes put here your view's code

Comment: <!-- modal placeholder-->
    <div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id='myModalContent'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: actually i am using modal and ui grid if i try to call modal using ui grid cell template then its not genertate ajax request